# Ciclo for javascript para crear una pirámide de números

Tags: javascript

bien lo que trato de hacer es que imprima los numeros dependiendo el valor de "j"
por ejemplo si pongo 4 tendria que hacer

```
1
12
123
1234
```

y ya lo hace solo el detalle es que no los imprime como en el ejemplo si no que todo lo hace hacia abajo, ayuda por favor.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=1
var n=0
var j=4
for(n; n<=j;n++){
for (i=1;i<=n;i++){

document.write(i )
 document.write("<br />")
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya lo solucione el espacio va en el otro ciclo

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=1
var n=0
var j=4
for(n; n<=j;n++){
for (i=1;i<=n;i++){

document.write(i)
}
document.write("<br/>")
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```